# How hidden classes allows faster access to properties in google's V8?

Tags: javascript, architecture, google

As [Lars Bak](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWhMKalEicY) and [Jay Conrod](http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation) described in several videos and papers, the main idea of hidden classes in V8 is to store concrete offset or transition to another hidden class which probably contains this offset for every object's property, instead of doing "slow" lookup in hashtable which contains all properties.

In old-fashioned way of property access, for example to get `point.x`, we need to calculate the hashcode from `x` and then go through array (if there wasn't hashcode-collision when property was added we'll get the value instantly). But in new-fashioned way we have a hidden class (just a `Map`?) and need to iterate through it to find out contains it the `x` key or not and only after that we can take property value by offset in `x` field. Or in more complicated case we need to do some additional steps through transitions to another hidden classes. So I don't see a difference between storing all properties in hashtable and using hidden classes. Maybe there is some assembly trick that I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 and other language implementations using similar techniques are just-in-time compilers. They generate code, and that generated code is speculatively optimized (with checks to fall back to slower, more general code if the specialization turns out to be invalid). So when generating code, the JIT compiler often has a good guess at what the hidden class of an object is — from type inference or from data collected while running the program — and it generates code like this:

```
compare hidden class pointer to address of assumed 
if not equal, de-optimize, otherwise:
access the property at a hard-coded offset
```

Each line of the above can be a single assembler instruction on x86. Since it assumes a hidden class when generating this code, the JIT compiler can retrieve the offset from the hidden class *at JIT compile time* and hard-code it in the code, so the code that runs often never even touches the hidden class.

Answer (score 2):

The key is that this is being used in a JIT which produces specialized code.

Let's say that have a function something like this:

```
function add_points(a, b) {
   return new Point(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}
```

V8 will actually generate different versions of this function, for different possible arguments that you pass in. For example, it would generate a version of the function that is only used when a and b are both members of a hidden Point class.

```
Point add_points(Point a, Point b) {
   return new Point(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}
```

The trick then is that since we know that this function will only actually be used for objects with the Hidden point class, x and y are always going to be at the same offset. So we don't have to look it up each time, the compiler looked it up once while building this function, and inserted the offset into the generated code.